# Reachability and notificationcenter

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I need my app to constantly listen for `reachability` changes and update my views according to the `network status`, i am thinking about using the `notificationcenter`, and let all my views listen for changes, but i have no idea how to implement this.

I know how to use the `notificationcenter` and `Reachability` but i can't seem to find a place to implement the `Reachability check`.

Where should i check for network changes, and notify the other `ViewControllers`?

I don't think `AppDelegate` is the right place, and if i put the `Reachability` check in a ViewController the network checking is only being performed as long as the `ViewController` is "active".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a "singleton" `Reachability` and initialize it at app launch.

Let the singleton check for reachability periodically, e.g. with `NSTimer`. It can then notify any other active views that registered with `NSNotificationCenter`.

```
// AppDelegate.m: 

@property (nonatomic, strong) Reachability *reachability;

// in applicationDidFinishLaunching...
self.reachability = [[Reachability alloc] init];
```

and

```
// Reachability.m

-(id)init {
   self = [super init];
   if (self) {
     [self setupTheTimer];
   }
   return self;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would create a singleton `NSObject` class that handles all the network checks.

Name it like NetworkChecker.

Create a delegate for the callback, like `NetworkCheckerDelegate` with a method like:

```
@protocol NetworkCheckerDelegate <NSObject>

-(void)networkStatusUpdated:(NSInteger)networkStatus;

@end

@interface NetworkChecker : NSObject
{
    id<NetworkCheckerDelegate> networkDelegate;
}
```

Add a method to start the network checking and add a delegate to it like:

```
+(void)updateNetworkWithDelegate:(id<NetworkCheckerDelegate>)delegate
{
    networkDelegate = delegate;

    //Set timer to do Reachability checks
}

-(void)timerIsCompleted
{
    //Do Reachability check

    if( newNetworkState != oldNetworkState ){
        [networkDelegate networkStatusUpdated:newNetworkState];
    }
}
```

Then in each `ViewController` you need it you can do (do this in viewDidLoad):

```
[NetworkChecker updateNetworkWithDelegate:self];
```

And implement the following to do something after the network status changed:

```
-(void)networkStatusUpdated:(NSInteger)networkStatus
```

Comment: Okay, but then i am only checking when i call [NetworkChecker updateNetworkWithDelegate:self] right?

I need constant network checking and notification

Comment: No that is just to enable the network checker for the current view. You can just call networkStatusUpdated: from within the NetworkChecker all the time to update the current view with the new network status

Comment: Can you please elaborate a little, perhaps with some more code?
I don't quite get it. :)

Comment: What is unclear? Creating the singleton? The delegate? The connection between the ViewControllers and the NetworkChecker?

Comment: I have created the class NetworkCheck : NSObject but i don't know how to create the singleton or the delegate, and how to use the Reachability code within the methods.

Comment: I have updated my answer and added some more code. It is a singleton as long as you don't instantiate it. Let me know if it works for you